# Py2App generating Segmentation fault: 11 on run OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app

I have a python application ready for production. I am able to build and run the application in Py2App's Alias mode. However, when I try to build it in production mode,
`python3 setup.py py2app`
it will indicate a successful build, but when I run, `./dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main`, immediately, I will get an error producing only, `Segmentation fault: 11`. I am running Python 3.6 and Py2App 0.14.1. Can anyone shed some light on where segmentation fault comes from? Obviously it is somewhere in my code, but there are a couple thousand lines and I don't want to post it right now. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that I was missing

```
'packages': 'certifi',
```

from my setup.py since I had some https links in my UI. I would suggest you make sure that

```
'argv_emulation': True,
```

is not in your setup.py and run the binary to see what the errors are and go from there.

In my case, I saw an error with mention of "URL" which eventually led me to think that maybe something about the links is causing the Seg Fault 11 and so it was!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, Stephen. It actually wasn't meant to be an answer. I saw that this has been dead for 3 months so I thought I would see if I can revive the thread and dig out the problem together but right after I posted, I figured out my problem, so I edited my answer. Perhaps, I should have added a comment instead right? Would be open to your recommendations on how to contribute better in this situation where I probably still didn't give a full answer for the posters specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it started to work after I removed `'argv_emulation': True` which I took from samples